# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS failed to connect to Cisco router (the wi-fi)

Tags: networking, wireless

My Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS  failed to connect to Cisco router (the wi-fi). But it can connect with other router (ISP router). And my other PC(windows10)/iphone can also connect to Cisco router. Just Ubuntu and the Cisco router failed to connect with each other. Any one know the reason?

Cisco router is RV110W.
thanks in advance

Comment: was the ISP router connection via wifi?

Comment: my cisco router connect ISP router with cable . i upgrade the ubuntu to 18.04.2 and disable the 02.11n protocol , now i can connect to wifi but the speed is very slow . i need to figure out how to speed up .

Comment: that's not clear to me. disabling 02.11n protocol was the only method for wifi to function? if so link what research lead you to this conclusion and choice. You should edit your original post to include all of this information. what you did and why is not clear right now.